# Secure way of using firebase's custom auth tokens for "in-house" passwordles authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

We have multiple custom requirements that essentially require us to use our own server and email api's for user authentication.

We are trying to re-create paswordless authentication flow and think we got it going. But I wanted to verify if below is accurate and in particular, if this is secure way of doing this.

1. Keeping email authentication disabled in firebase
2. Sending user's email from app client to custom server
3. Using firebase admin sdk with `createCustomToken`, where uid is user's email
4. Sending an email to the user with a link to app, where custom token is attached (we handle rate limitting)
5. Verifying this custom token within the app using `signInWithCustomToken`

Am I missing anything here, in particular any security caveats I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach sounds correct, and matches with the Firebase documentation on [signing in with a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk).

The only security concern is usually around step 4, since that goes through unsecured channels and this is susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks. In practice it's not usually a problem, but remains something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

That approach sounds correct.

The only security concern is usually around step 4, since that goes through unsecured channels and this is susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks. In practice it's not usually a problem, but remains something to be aware of.